# How to stop sas without closing it?

Tags: sas

I have started executing a command but it appears that it fell into infinite loop. I really dont want to close the system. How can I break the execution without exiting sas ???

PS: i tried to press break button on the keyboard and on the sas tab panel ... does not work

Comment: in the SAS IDE, sometimes you have to wait a bit for the break button to register.  Sometimes you have no choice but to kill the application and relaunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Pause` on Windows works for me.